# How to send a message to a moderator

Tags: discussion

I made a post but the post was deleted.  I do not know why.
How do I send a message to a moderator to find out?

Comment: We do have a [Tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) for new users to start their journey on the right foot. There's also quite an extensive [Help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help) section, unlike most other sites, which tend to be geared more towards the forum style. Stack Exchange is unlike the others, it's a pure question & answer site, so it's often very different from what people are used to from other sites.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you posted a follow-up question in the place reserved for answers. Ask Different is not a forum site, please take the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) and look at the [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help) to understand how the site works.

New questions can be asked by clicking on the "Ask Question" button on the main site.

Comment: It should not be this hard to know where one can or can not post a comment.

Comment: You have learned one of the design goals. Stack Exchange makes it easy for anyone to ask or answer and much harder to comment. We believe that reducing chit chat and noise is important and commenting restrictions are one way to enforce that with new accounts.

Comment: Said to say in my experince your goals of making it "easy" for anyone to ask or answer a question has been very hard in my case.    I hope that my edit shows that if my answer was left to grow as I was going to, it can be seen that it is in fact an answer or at the very least and expansion to the answer given.  

Please note that for a dislexic like me some nouns have very little difference between them.  Example "Answer" v "Comment" may have a difference in a dictornay but that does not always show up in the ways we think.

Answer (score 0):

Asking here on meta is an excellent way to get all the moderators to have a look. Everyone past a set level of reputation gets to [cast votes to delete posts or close them so there are many moderators here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators).

---

In your case you posted an answer here that didn’t meet the quality standard for a direct answer to the question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/465557/5472

All first posts on a site by a user enter a review queue that trusted members of the community can view to ensure everyone has a good experience. Two users evaluated your “answer” as “not an answer” and after those comments a third user flagged it as not an answer. I agreed and deleted the post about 6 hours after it was initially posted and reviewed.

You now have answered a second time, and that answer doesn’t look to have enough detail to be kept up. I’d rather it not get down votes while you have time to edit it into shape.

I would recommend you edit your original post and then flag it for one of the elected moderators to review once you have all your edits done. This can happen in a day, a week or a month. Take your time.

Comment: OK but I am unsure as to how to do this considering the post was deleted before I got a chance to edit it.   My post was meant as a question to the original post and if I had been given time to add to it then it would have turned in to an answer that may have been useful to others.

Comment: Are you not able to see the deleted post by starting from your user profile page? @Steve here is the edit link for the post in question…. https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/465557/edit

Comment: @steve You can also just post the answer.

Comment: I will check after tea, but as a dyslexic this how process is make me wish not to share with a community information others may fine usfull.  As mod's you should keep in mind the needs and problems that people with these sorts of dificaltys have.   Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I have edited the deleted post/answer/comment and I hope it meats the quality standard for a direct answer to the question.    If it does not then please be explicit in why/how?